# Change post background based on group ID on IP.Board

Tags: invision-power-board

I would like my premium members to have a slightly different post background when they post on my forum.

I know I can do this by adding a group ID class to the  tag.

Ultimately, I want it to look like this:

7 is the ID number for my premium members.

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
<div class='post_block hentry clear clearfix <if test="isSolvedCss:|:$post['post']['_isMarkedAnswered']">solved</if> <if test="postQueued:|:$post['post']['_isHidden']">moderated</if> ***{$author['member_group_id']}***' id='post_id_{$post['post']['pid']}'>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to use $author, which doesn't really exists in this context. What you want to use, is the post's author.

Try this:

```
{$post['author']['member_group_id']}
```

so your code should end up like:

```
<div class='post_block hentry clear clearfix <if test="isSolvedCss:|:$post['post']['_isMarkedAnswered']">solved</if> <if test="postQueued:|:$post['post']['_isHidden']">moderated</if> {$post["author"]["member_group_id"]}' id='post_id_{$post["post"]["pid"]}'>
```

Hopefully this helps you.